# How to create the wsp package in visual studio 2010 with following features?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, wspbuilder

I want to create a wsp package. When I deploy it, it must add features such as two SharePoint lists, one webpart, one image library sequentially. Can I do this in WSPBuilder? I want to deploy this on a site collection level (scope). How do I build this package?

Using Google, I found I must install WSPBuilder templates, but as I downloaded and installed, I could not find WSPBuilder Template in the Visual Studio -> new Project window.

Is there another way to do the same thing with something other than WSPBuilder?

Comment: closing this as it as a duplicate of a newer question which is more up-to-date.